# Plastic Ceiling box

Tags: ceiling, junction-box

I have a 10.5 lb. 42 in. ceiling fan.  the existing box installed by builder is a deep rectangle plastic box which is attached through the top to sistered stud attached to a joist.

Comment: You appear to have missed the part where you have a question. Hit the edit button and ask whatever it is you intended to ask...

Comment: Does it say "Fan rated"?  If not, *don't do it*.   They make "old work" fan boxes designed to retrofit without busting up drywall.

Comment: Is mounting the ceiling fan directly to the blocking that the box is attached to an option?  Also, can you post photos of the inside of the box please?